# I can't write into the shell of the PyCharm when I can write to the shell of Online Python Compiler (Interpreter) of Programiz

Tags: pycharm

I'm doing the tutorial by Programiz and I'm using Pycharm to exercise my knowledge but it seems that I can't write into the Run tab of the Pycharm (or the Shell).

Here's my code:

class PowTwo:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of powers of two"""

```
def __init__(self, max = 0):
    self.max = max

def __iter__(self):
    self.n = 0
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.n <= self.max:
        result = 2 ** self.n
        self.n += 1
        return result
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

I can clearly write to the shell of the Online Compiler but I can't to the PyCharm. What's the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1lxu.png)

[unlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NibaF.png)

Comment: You should rename your links, give them human-readable names.

Answer (score 0):

Okay :)

Pycharm is for more complex projects. While you are learning the basics you can use python's built-in IDLE.

Read [this](https://realpython.com/python-idle/) article, I think it will help you understand how it works.

I suppose you have installed python (else you can download it from [hear](https://www.python.org/downloads/)). If you installed it, you need to either open the python IDLE and create a new file or create a new file with `.py` extension and open it with the IDLE. Then when you wrote your `PowTwo` class there, you can simply run it with `F5` and use the interactive shell.

In pycharm, it is not a python shell, instead it is a cmd terminal. If you really want to use pycharm, you have two options:

Use the python console instead of run and import your file (`import test`) or use the terminal and type python to launch the console and import your file. (I suggest the first option)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm's Run tab is only for interacting with the program while it is running, it isn't an interactive Python shell like the online REPL is, that's what the Python Console is for.

Open the Python Console tab, enter `import [filename without .py]` and you've got what you're looking for.